# Passwordless SSH using cgi-perl script

Tags: linux, apache2, cgi, ssh-keys, setuid

This is my first shot at trying out cgi-perl scripts. I have SSH keys set up between my (root user) local machine and a remote machine. I'm trying to run a command on the remote box and display the output on a webpage hosted from my local machine. The script runs fine from command line however, it throws SSH key error when called from the webpage because the user running the script is apache and not root. Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Create SSH keys for user apache?

Comment: The user that logs in to the remote box would need sudo permissions to get the status. I do not think the admins would appreciate too many accounts to have that access.

Comment: @AV: But creating a SSH key pair for root is not a good idea either. Especially if this should be used for an automated web process.

Comment: But apart from creating the ssh keys for apache, is there any other option? At least for the purposes of learning :)

Answer (score 3):

If you not already have a restricted account, create one, create the SSH keys and add the commands that the user should be allowed to execute via `sudo` to the `/etc/sudoers` file (e.g. via `visudo`, [more about `sudoers`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821)). This is the safest approach imho.
You can even restrict the user in such a way, that he can **only** execute these commands. For

I don't know about Perl, but normal you can specify which user should be logged in via SSH:

```
ssh user@host
```

**Update:**

Are you using the `Net::SSH::Perl` module? If so, just set the `user` accordingly:

```
my $host = "perlhowto.com";
my $user = "user";
my $password = "password";

#-- set up a new connection
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
#-- authenticate
$ssh->login($user, $pass);
```

(I just copied and pasted this code from [`perlhowto.com`](http://www.perlhowto.com/execute_commands_on_remote_machines_using_ssh))

Comment: ok. I just would need to then talk to the admin of the remote host to get that access set up. But is there a way I can make the script run as root when called from the webpage?

Comment: @AV: As I said, normally you can specify which user should be logged in via SSH: `user@host` which would be `root@host` in your case. But it can also be that you are not allowed to ssh as root.

Comment: Actually, the root user on the local machine connects as "dummy@remote" and the dummy user has been granted the permissions to fetch the status. Yes I will try to follow the route of getting apache's ssh keys linked to the dummy user.